# Synology Route traffic to Docker

Tags: routing, ip, ip-routing, synology

I have:

```
+------+                                                         +-------------+
|      +NIC1 (192.168.1.100) <--> Router <--> (192.168.1.2) NIC1 +             |
|  PC  |                                                         |     DSM     |
|      +NIC2 (10.10.0.100) <--Peer-2-Peer---> (10.10.0.2)   NIC2 +             |
+------+                                                         |   [DOCKER]  |
                                                                 |(172.17.0.2) |
                                                                 +-------------+
```

inside docker i have web server that running on port 1337 (http://172.17.0.2:1337) - this site is accessible from DSM

question: how to route traffic from PC NIC 2 to my docker container?

so i can access from pc, e.g. http://somewebsite.local <-- route to 10.10.0.2 translate to 172.17.0.2:1337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so apparently, my */home/parse/parse-dashboard/config.json*:

```
"serverURL": "http://172.17.0.2:1337/parse"
```

should point to my DSM machine which is:

```
"serverURL": "http://192.168.1.2:1337/parse"
```